# Mixpanel disable tracking in certain environment for iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, mixpanel

I would like to disable tracking by Mixpanel when the app is in development profile. This can be done easily in Google Analytics for iOS by calling a method to disable tracking . But for Mixpanel for iOS ,I couldn't find a similar method.  Any idea how to implement this  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just not initialize MixPanel, by using the `DEBUG` define like:

```
#ifndef DEUGB // Debug is not defined 
   [Mixpanel sharedInstanceWithToken:MIXPANEL_TOKEN];
#ednif
```

Comment: Thanks ,I already tried that it show the warning in my console. So I tried to find a better alternative. Anyway, if there is none. This is probable the best way to go

Answer (score 0):

You're actually encouraged to create a separate project for debugging / development
ProjectName-Develop
Then if DEBUG is defined, use that project's API token.